# Application Loader: I can't save my ITMSP file

Tags: xcode, in-app-purchase, application-loader

When creating a new in app purchase with Application Loader, I can't seem to deliver my package, or save the ApplicationLoader configuration (.ITMSP) file.

I seem to get the following message:

> The document X could not be saved as Y.itsmp. The file doesn’t exist.

Of course it doesn't exist - I'm creating it!

Answer (score 0):

This one confused me for a while too.

Click the title bar and type a name in, press enter, save, job done.
[image: ApplicationLoader caption bar]

As blogged here: http://bit.ly/1FS3TcT